# How to see what is my Amazon elastic beanstalk rds password?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database, elastic-beanstalk

How can I retrieve the database password for my Elastic Beanstalk environment running on the "**Aurora MySQL**" engine?

I have an IAM user with the necessary permissions to manage the application, but I couldn't find the password in the **Secret Manager** or **S3**.

I tried using the AWS console command

`aws elasticbeanstalk describe-configuration-settings --application-name <application-name> --environment-name <environment-name> --query 'ConfigurationSettings[0].OptionSettings[?OptionName==DBPassword].Value' --output text` ,

but it only returns the password query enclosed in single quotes. If I remove the quotes, the command returns nothing.

Since the site is in production mode, I can't reset the password.

I came across this link ([How to see what is my Amazon rds password](https://serverfault.com/questions/950963/how-to-see-what-is-my-amazon-rds-password)), which suggests that it may not be possible to access the password for a standard RDS instance.

Can anyone help me retrieve the database password for my Elastic Beanstalk environment running on the "**Aurora MySQL**" engine?

Thanks in advance.